# New concrete ceiling leaking water

Tags: water, concrete, leak, roof

I have hired a contractor to build a patio style concrete roof for my hotel. He is in the middle of construction but when it starts to rain, I can see water starting to leak through the ceiling. What is the reason for this? Is the contractor using cheap material or not building it properly?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Have you asked the contractor about it?

Comment: Simple: Water comes through concrete.

Comment: I don't fully trust my contractor which is why I am asking. He mentioned he needs to add water-proofing to the concrete to avoid the leaks. I just want to know if he's giving me genuine information or if he's using cheap material and concrete.